# CMS Page Memory limit has been reached

Tags: magento-1.9, image

I can't upload images on my CMS home page, it says "Memory limit has been reached", i've been searching on internet a fix, and i found this one saying to change this code on Gd2.php ( /lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php ) :

```
    protected function _convertToByte($memoryValue)
{
    if (stripos($memoryValue, 'M') !== false) {
        return (int)$memoryValue * 1024 * 1024;
    }
    elseif (stripos($memoryValue, 'KB') !== false) {
        return (int)$memoryValue * 1024;
    }

   return (int)$memoryValue;
}
```

to

```
protected function _convertToByte($memoryValue)
{
     /*
     if (stripos($memoryValue, 'M') !== false) {
         return (int)$memoryValue * 1024 * 1024;
     }
     elseif (stripos($memoryValue, 'KB') !== false) {
         return (int)$memoryValue * 1024;
     }

     return (int)$memoryValue;
     */
     return 2147483648;
     //1024*1024*1024*2 = 2G
}
```

(Yes i removed the commentary codes )

but in my Gd2.php the code is different, here's the code i have:

```
protected function _convertToByte($memoryValue)
    {
        $memoryValue = trim($memoryValue);
        if (empty($memoryValue)) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (preg_match('~^([1-9][0-9]*)[\s]*(k|m|g)b?$~i', $memoryValue, $matches)) {
            $option = strtolower($matches[2]);
            $memoryValue = $matches[1];
            switch ($option) {
                case 'g':
                    $memoryValue *= 1024;
                    // no break
                case 'm':
                    $memoryValue *= 1024;
                    // no break
                case 'k':
                    $memoryValue *= 1024;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        $memoryValue = (int)$memoryValue;

        return $memoryValue > 0 ? $memoryValue : 0;
    }
```

Comment: Which Magento version you are using?

Comment: Hi @Macas, i'm using version 1.9.3.1, it's in the tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to increase your PHP memory limit, it's not a Magento related issue, but rather a PHP/Web server one.

Try increasing the following PHP configuration values in your **php.ini** :

- post_max_size
- upload_max_filesize

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, i would to try those configs but i can't find the php.ini in my ftp, i tried the phpinfo but it leads me to /opt/alt/php55/etc  but i can't find that location in my ftp, i can only fint the php.ini.sample but i think it's not there

Comment: You most likely don't have access to that folder as that is system administrator land. I think this is not a developer job, it's a dev ops job. So I would contact the system administrator to sort it out if I were you. Also even if you could find the php.ini, I believe you have to restart the web server afterwards which you cannot do from FTP anyway so yeah, dev opts job.